# MySQL stop responding

Tags: database-performance, mysql-5.6

In a production environment, our Master MySQL 5.6.26 stop responding.

Our business handles about 1500 transactions per minute but there are times that nothing gets processes for many seconds (18 seconds this time).

We are logging show full processlist output every few seconds and we find the usual queries that normally took a fraction of a second holding for many seconds. But no indication of why.

In the past, we have an issue with storage provider that has almost a second of latency and everything fell apart, but now is not the case, normal 5 to 20 milliseconds latency.

What should I look?

Comment: Check with the data

Comment: Who's database are you using? Some database management platforms build on top of a vanilla MySQL database with their own stuff.  I know that Azure has had problems with database queries randomly failing.

Comment: You might want to ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/, but you should provide much more information about the tables you have, the queries you are running, the indices you have, etc...